# SQL para contar os registros que têm um campo com valor repetido

Tags: sql-server, query

Pessoal preciso de uma Query que faça uma contagem de valores que tenho no banco

No meu sistema, eu tenho um multiselect que podem selecionar mais de um opção.

Queria uma ajuda de vocês, eu nunca mexi com query, preciso de uma Query que conte quantos números 1 tenho no banco desta variável, quantos números 2 tenho no banco desta variável, 
Sendo que quando tiver mais de uma opção selecionada no banco ele fica assim 1, 2 , 9, 10.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Uso SQLServer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu fiz esta query, só que ela conta somente os valores que não tem virgula

```
  SELECT DISTINCT Pressaus ,COUNT(*) AS quantidade
  FROM jud_Processos
 GROUP BY Pressaus
 ORDER BY quantidade DESC
```

Comment: Assim fica difícil ajudar, você preciso mostrar o schema da tabela. Pra contar você usa `count` combinado com `group by`

Comment: @RicardoPontual Atulizei o topico

Comment: Qual o tipo da coluna `Pressaus`? `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @DaniloFavato Sim está como VARCHAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma como os dados estão armazenados no banco de dados dificulta muito esse tipo de consulta pois os dados não estão [normalizados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados).

O código abaixo realiza sua consulta, mas é necessário saber de antemão quantas são as opções que podem ser escolhidas, pois voce precisará criar um `CASE WHEN` para cada uma delas.

Considerando que as alternativas são os números de `0` a `12`

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "0,%" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "%,0" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "%,0,%" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus = "0" THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS "Total Opcao0",
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "1,%" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "%,1" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "%,1,%" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus = "1" THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS "Total Opcao1",
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "2,%" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "%,2" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "%,2,%" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus = "2" THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS "Total Opcao2",
  .
  .  -- CASE WHEN para cada opcao...
  .
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "12,%" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "%,12" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE "%,12,%" THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus = "12" THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS "Total Opcao12"
FROM jud_Processos;
```

Basicamente cada `CASE WHEN` cria uma coluna para cada opção e nessa coluna é inserido o numero `1` caso a linha possua a opção no campo `Pressaus`. Como a opção pode estar no início, no meio, no fim ou ser exatamente o campo precisamos de 4 cláusulas `WHEN` uma para cada possibilidade.

Depois a funcao `SUM()` soma quantas vezes cada alternativa apareceu.

Exemplo no sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e14763/23

Comment: Cara funcionou perfeitamente, muto obrigado!

Comment: caso eu queria falar sobre uma mudança neste seu select preciso abrir um novo topico? ou posso conversar com você aqui mesmo ?

Comment: Sou novo aqui... não sei como funcionam essas regras, mas se for uma nova duvida acredito que seja melhor criar uma nova pergunta.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223991/sql-para-contar-os-registros-que-t%C3%AAm-um-campo link do novo topico