# SQL para contar os registros que têm um campo

Tags: sql-server, query

Boa tarde,

Não sei como funciona as regras do topico, pedi ajuda em um topico anterior e um dos membros acabou me ajudando só que queria tirar mais uma duvida sobre a ajuda.

A query que ele me ajudou foi está abaixo e está correta

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '0,%' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '%,0' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '%,0,%' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus = '0' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS 'Apoio Profissional',
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '1,%' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '%,1' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '%,1,%' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus = '1' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS 'Cirurgia',
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '2,%' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '%,2' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '%,2,%' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus = '2' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS 'Consulta Médica',
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '3,%' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '%,3' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '%,3,%' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus = '3' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS 'Custeio',

  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '4,%' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '%,4' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus LIKE '%,4,%' THEN 1
    WHEN Pressaus = '4' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS 'Exame Médico'
FROM jud_Processos;
```

Está query ela seria posta para um gráfico do meu sistema. Está query abaixo é a query antiga do meu sistema.

```
SELECT
                        CASE Tipo
                            WHEN 0 THEN 'Apoio Profissional'
                            WHEN 1 THEN 'Cirurgia'
                            WHEN 2 THEN 'Consulta Médica'
                            WHEN 3 THEN 'Custeio'
                            WHEN 4 THEN 'Exame Médico'
                            WHEN 5 THEN 'Fitoterápico/Homeopático'
                            WHEN 6 THEN 'Fraldas/Lenços'
                            WHEN 7 THEN 'Internação Compulsória'
                            WHEN 8 THEN 'Internação Domiciliar'
                            WHEN 9 THEN 'Internação Não-Compulsória'
                            WHEN 10 THEN 'Leito'
                            WHEN 11 THEN 'Leito de UTI'
                            WHEN 12 THEN 'Medicamento'
                            WHEN 13 THEN 'Produto de Saúde'
                            WHEN 14 THEN 'Suplemento Alimentar'
                            WHEN 15 THEN 'Tratamento de Saúde'
                            WHEN 16 THEN 'UTI/Aérea'
                            WHEN 17 THEN 'UTI Móvel/Transferência Hospitalar'
                            WHEN 18 THEN 'Órtese/Prótese'
                            WHEN 19 THEN 'Procedimento Eletivo'
                            WHEN 20 THEN 'Outros'
                        END AS Title,
                        (Processos) AS Count
                        FROM (
                            SELECT p.Tipo,
                            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
                                SELECT COUNT(*) AS Processos
                                FROM jud_Prodserv
                                WHERE Tipo = p.Tipo
                                GROUP BY ProcessoId
                            ) Sub) AS Processos,
                            COUNT(*) AS Count
                            FROM jud_Prodserv p
                            INNER JOIN jud_Processos pr ON p.ProcessoId = pr.ProcessoId
                            WHERE pr.Status = 1 AND pr.Trancado = 1 {dados}
                            GROUP BY Tipo
                        ) Sub
                        ORDER BY Tipo;
```

Gostaria de saber se tem como se basear nela, pois no no **WHERE** tem entre **Chaves** a palavra **{dados}** está chave gera os gráficos do sistema. é possivel se basear na query antiga do meu sistema?

Comment: Leonardo, se entendi bem sua duvida é como transpor os dados da consulta. Já que na primeira consulta as opções estão dispostas em colunas, mas na segunda as opções estão nas linhas, correto?

Comment: Isso exato, fora isso tem o WHERE pr.Status = 1 AND pr.Trancado = 1 {dados}

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta, mas sem saber direito o esquema das tabelas fica difícil imaginar as `JOINS`. Tente melhorar a pergunta colocando exemplos de saídas e a parte do modelo Entidade-Relacionamento que importa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sem o esquema das tabelas fica difícil entender como os `JOINS` devem funcionar, mas caso o seu problema é transpor a primeira consulta, você pode trocar os `CASE WHEN` por `SUBQUERIES` unidas:

```
SELECT "Apoio Profissional" AS Title, Count(*) AS Count
FROM jud_Processos
WHERE
    Pressaus LIKE "0,%" OR
    Pressaus LIKE "%,0" OR
    Pressaus LIKE "%,0,%" OR
    Pressaus = "0"

UNION ALL

SELECT "Cirurgia" AS Title, Count(*) AS Count
FROM jud_Processos
WHERE
    Pressaus LIKE "1,%" OR
    Pressaus LIKE "%,1" OR
    Pressaus LIKE "%,1,%" OR
    Pressaus = "1"

UNION ALL

SELECT "Consulta Medica" AS Title, Count(*) AS Count
FROM jud_Processos
WHERE
    Pressaus LIKE "2,%" OR
    Pressaus LIKE "%,2" OR
    Pressaus LIKE "%,2,%" OR
    Pressaus = "2"
```

Comment: Deste jeito funcionou também, pra falar a verdade não precisa ter o INNER JOIN porque vou usar apenas a tabela jud_Processos, só que queria saber como posso colocar {dados} no meio da query para exibir o grafico na pagina

Comment: Cara funcionou no final do where de cara select, eu coloquei {dados} e exibiu, te agradeço mais uma vez!

Comment: Deixa eu te fazer uma pergunta, Caso no primeiro select "Apoio Profissional" o resultado for ZERO, tem como colocar para esconder essa opção? tipo na hora de executar o select não mostrar a opção, somente quando for ZERO

Comment: Muda a ultima linha do `WHERE` para `AND NOT Pressaus = "0"`

Comment: Ainda fica mostrando

Comment: Então não entendi sua pergunta, se não é para mostrar nada, só retirar toda a clausula `SELECT`, o que eu fiz ai em cima foi empilhar varias consultas uma em cima da outra com `UNION`